# Is there a good equivalent for the Italian proverb "Non tutte le ciambelle riescono col buco"?

Tags: idiom-requests, translation, phrase-requests, proverb-requests, italian

One of my favorite Italian sayings is

> *Non tutte le ciambelle riescono col buco* (literally "Not all donuts
> come out with holes").

It usually gets a smile from another Italian speaker, because it's a nice way to conclude (even serious) discussions about things that are complex and not working 100% according to plan and for which there may be no solution. It's a wry verbal shrug.

The only rough equivalents I've come up with are "What are you going to do?", "C’est la vie/That's life", "We/they can't all be winners", "You can't win them all", and "The best laid plans..."

**(you) can't win them all**

> A phrase said, often as an attempt at consolation, when one has lost
> or failed to achieve a desired result, especially after previous
> success. "Them" is sometimes abbreviated as "'em." [Farlex Dictionary
> of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+win+%27em+all)

**what are you going to do?**

> US informal
> Used to say that there is nothing you can do to make a
> situation better [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/what-are-you-going-to-do)

But some of the above are, in fact, used chiefly as consolations; the Italian is armchair philosophy in a nutshell. I haven't heard or seen an expression that captures the essence of the Italian: *sometimes we simply need to resign ourselves to that which is beyond our control, perfection may not be possible, and perhaps a bit of imperfection/individuality isn't a bad thing.*

(Google Translate outputs "Not all donuts succeed with a hole" :-) *Succeed/be able to* is the usual translation of the Italian verb *riuscire*, but it would be hard to use *succeed* here idiomatically without twisting the sentence into, well, a pretzel.)

Speaking in my native English, when a situation arises that's just right for the Italian saying, I resort to "There's an expression in Italian, "*Non tutte ...*" followed by an English translation. It's usually enough for the listener to appreciate the original, but *am I missing a good English equivalent?* I'm looking for something that's not a pure or brusk consolation ("Suck it up!") and, if possible, incorporates "look on the bright(er) side" or even "non-conformity counts too". (Something with humor as well would be a home run.)

English excels at sopping up individual words from other languages like a sponge to give us so many nuances in meaning. Expressions and whole proverbs seem to have a much harder time making the jump from language to language.

By the way, *[zeppole](https://www.google.com/search?q=zeppole&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=AOaemvIBsaARbHUWP94a_K9GOBOkV-tc4Q:1639488978951&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi558-xtOP0AhVWlGoFHTEXDSMQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=933&bih=515&dpr=1.5)* are small Italian donuts made (intentionally) without holes. Larger ones with assorted fillings like jelly donuts are *[bomboloni](https://www.google.com/search?q=italian%20bomboloni&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiZ0uWytOP0AhXNG98KHchlCDQQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=italian%20bombalon&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQARgAMgYIABAKEBg6BwgjEO8DECc6BQgAEIAEOggIABCABBCxAzoECAAQQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoGCAAQBRAeOgYIABAIEB46BAgAEBhQrApY0ShgmTpoAHAAeACAAVSIAbcKkgECMTeYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=1Z24YdmTGM23_AbIy6GgAw&bih=515&biw=933&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911)*.

[Some edits made, thanks to those who have commented.]

Comment: Other phrases that come to mind with a related meaning (but that I suspect fall foul of your "not chiefly consolation" criterion, hence a comment rather than an answer) include "That's the way the cookie crumbles" (and variants e.g. "That's the way the mop flops").

Comment: Is the gist of that saying meant to imply that while all donuts are formed with holes some puff up and close while baking/frying (implying random chance is responsible) or that some donuts start out without holes by design implying not everyone conforms to the norm or something else?

Comment: @psmears Yes, I'm looking for a non-consolation, maybe-look-on-the-bright(er)-side. Thanks, I've added that to the question.

Comment: @Jim The former. The plan is for holes, but some fry up without. And yes, I think there is a non-conformity aspect as well. I've added that to the question--thank you.

Comment: I am puzzled as to why anyone would downvote this question. It is interesting and appropriate, relating to the finding of good usage. I have upvoted.

Comment: I think anything could be consolatory or less so depending on who says it and the context. Surely "look on the bright side" is by its nature consolatory? "You have to kiss a lot of frogs to find your prince" or "It's the ones that are cracked that the light shines through" are obviously consolatory; "You can't make an omelet without breaking eggs" is sometimes used to advocate revolutionary violence so to that extent it may seem more brutal, but it could certainly be used in other more benevolent contexts.

Comment: @StuartF For me, what the English expressions lack is the "maybe it's not so bad" take on the situation. We're not looking for the perfect "prince among all donuts" and a donut without a hole certainly doesn't go to waste (just to waist). "Look on the bright side" is certainly upbeat, but lacks lacks humor, and might need to be followed by saying exactly what the bright side is. And the bright side may be only that perfection isn't possible.  I'm just nitpicking.

Comment: Funnily enough I'm put in mind of a domain-specific quote in statistics--"All models are wrong, but some are useful." (George Box) But that's not at all helpful for an idiomatic translation to English (vs Data Science). Though it's also a more extreme case--no donuts are perfect, but some are tasty?

Comment: "They can't all be winners": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ht4Ei3pdR8 (It certainly doesn't have that positive outlook that you want, though!)

Comment: I think the translation can be adopted in English because it is funny and it conveys the idea clearly. In English, the best common expression would be "not everything goes as planned". A broader yet simple idiomatic expression would be "life happens".

Comment: @DjinTonic Yeah, that's what reminded me of the movie scene. I mostly mentioned it just because it was funny, not as real suggestion. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: There's an Eleanor Roosevelt quote that's not too far off in the philosophical tone:  ["If life were predictable it would cease to be life, and be without flavor."](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Eleanor_Roosevelt#Tomorrow_Is_Now_(1963))  But it's not a common proverb.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have the word "equivalent" in my question title and not only the "proverb" tag. I like it.

Comment: I suppose someone looking down on someone for whom things weren't working would be displaying a holier-than-thou attitude.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is that another one of your Pun-ic War jokes, Edwin?

Comment: No; Homer had brought about the extinction of donuts well before the Punic Wars.

Answer (score 3):

**When life gives you lemons, make lemonade.**

> *When life gives you lemons, make lemonade* is a proverbial phrase used to encourage optimism and a positive can-do attitude in the face
> of adversity or misfortune. Lemons suggest sourness or difficulty in
> life; making lemonade is turning them into something positive or
> desirable.

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_life_gives_you_lemons,_make_lemonade)]

Comment: I can see the inspiration behind that: my "Suck it up!" became "Go suck on a lemon!" and then "Hey look, lemons!" etc. :-)  Not bad!

Comment: Yes, it's common, but I'm not sure it has the charm of the original.

Comment: @aparente001 That would be a perfect ELU tag for my question: "charm-requests"

Answer (score 2):

My impression is the there is probably no English proverb that conveys the exact meaning and spirit of the Italian one:

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/italiano-inglese/ciambella)  suggests:

> things can’t be expected to turn out right every time.

which, IMO, is as close as possible to the Italian usage.

From the site:  [Amazing Italian Words That There’s No Translation For:](http://blog.learnhownow.com/2016/09/23/amazing-italian-words-theres-no-translation/)

“Non tutte le ciambelle riescono col buco”

> This literally translates as ‘not all donuts come out with a hole’. As an Italian, you might use it to mean ‘not everything turns out as planned’. We love this for two reasons. Firstly, it is very philosophical and so are we. Secondly, it is all about donuts and so are we.

Comment: That's an excellent translation, but is just that, a translation and not a saying or proverb. I quote the Italian in English conversation because it's a practical truism that sums up situations with humor.

Comment: @DjinTonic - not all proverbs have a perfect twin in other languages. If there were one you would find it in dictionaries. Proverbs often  summarize  a cultural aspect that’s  typical of a specific  culture, and the Italian one is different from the Anglo Saxon one.

Comment: That is true, but I belive the Collins site provides translations. I realize that  we won't have a perfect match in English, but I don't know every saying and could be missing something pithy or witty.

Comment: Given the second quote (from Amazing Italian Words...), one saying that comes to mind is "No plan survives contact with the enemy". Alternatively, I might make some sort of reference to Murphy's Law, whose canonical phrasing is "Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong."

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - none of the two sayings is close to the Italian one, sorry. The sense is simpler than the OP is making.

Comment: I like the comment at the site mentioned in this answer because it emphasizes the philosophical bent. The proverb is, on the surface, just pointing out a fact--you are invited to apply its philosophy to the situation. As I pointed out, a hole-less donut is a far cry from a tragedy.

Comment: @DjinTonic - the same site tells you also that there is no English equivalent for that saying, sorry.

Comment: @user66974  I wouldn't be surprised if there is no exact equivalent, but it doesn't hurt to ask.  By "the site" I assume we're talking about one person, Nicola, the author of the article. Of course if a dictionary doesn't have a given word, it doesn't mean you won't find it in another dictionary :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about "that's the way the cookie crumbles"?  It keeps the food connection and the cookies are still good to eat even though they are in inconvenient crumbs.

In non food related phrases, I would either vote for a reference to Murphy's Law or suggest "best laid plans of mice and men ...".